# Azure App Service - failed to retrieve available site extensions. please check the resource usage of your app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

[image]

I have the attached error when I'm trying to add an extension to my Azure App Service. All metrics are normal for this app. Moreover, I am able to add an extension to another app service from the same subscription but different resource group.

Thank you.

Comment: which extension are you trying to add to the `Azure app service` ?

Comment: @Harshitha, thanks for your reply. We are trying to add Datadog APM extension.

Comment: Could you please let me know the details of the App Service(RGLocation, App Service Plan), in which the app service is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add site Extensions to Azure App Service without any issues.

I have tried with two different Azure Apps in different Resource Groups.

For One Azure App Service which is having less memory usage, Iam able to add the Extension without any error.

Click on `Accept legal terms` and continue while adding extension.

[image]

For the second app service, which is low on memory, I got the below error.
[image]

***Memory Usage***

Check the memory usage of the App service Plan and Azure Web App.

In `Azure App Service` => Under `App Service Plan` click on `Quotas`

[image]

***For App Service Plan***

[image]

You can add `Extensions` even from KUDU Console.

In `Azure portal` => Your `Azure App Service` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `Site extensions`  => Click on `Gallery`

In Search box enter `Datadog` and click on `Search`
Related extensions will be displayed. Click on `+` symbol and continue to install.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harshitha. I am now looking into the above options you gave. Meanwhile, we already raised a request to Azure with regards to this issue.